# Javascript increment value on click (working for one click++)

Tags: javascript

When a user clicks a `<button>`, I need to increment a value.

My script works, but when I do a second click, it's hanging on the first value it's got.

What's going wrong with it please?

```js
var global_score;
var current_score;
function question_answer(event_sender, sent_answer) {
 global_score;
 current_score = document.querySelector(".game-current-score-main h2");
 if(sent_answer == "increment") {
  global_score++;
  current_score.innerHTML = "Score:" + global_score;
 }
 else if(sent_answer == "decrement")
 {
  global_score--;
        current_score.innerHTML = "Score:" + global_score;
 }
};
```

Comment: Can you post the part where you listen for clicks? And are you certain the function is firing each click?

Comment: Can you initialise your global_score to 0 or something, then try?

Comment: where you are getting globalscore

Comment: Yes, @Smit solved my problem. Thank you all! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var global_score = 0; // initialize
var current_score;
function question_answer(event_sender, sent_answer) {
    global_score; // you do not need this line
    current_score = document.querySelector(".game-current-score-main h2");
    if(sent_answer == "increment") {
        global_score++;
        current_score.innerHTML = "Score:" + global_score;
    }
    else if(sent_answer == "decrement")
    {
        global_score--;
        current_score.innerHTML = "Score:" + global_score;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You where almost there! All you have to change is set the global values to 0 then it will work

https://jsfiddle.net/nmo5vmd3/

```js
    var global_score = 0; // change here
    var current_score = 0; // change here
    function question_answer(event_sender, sent_answer) {
     global_score; // you do not need this line cause it does nothing
     //current_score = document.querySelector(".game-current-score-main h2");
     if(sent_answer == "increment") {
      global_score++;
      current_score.innerHTML = "Score:" + global_score;
     }
     else if(sent_answer == "decrement")
     {
      global_score--;
            current_score.innerHTML = "Score:" + global_score;
     }
        console.log(global_score); // you do not need this line, it does nothing
    };
```

```html
<div onclick="question_answer('xx', 'increment')">
        increment
    </div>
    <div onclick="question_answer('xx', 'decrement')">
        decrement
    </div>
```